# Do I have to pay for the appointment and biometrics

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

After paying the visa fee, I proceeded to book an appointment and biometrics but I don't know if filled that section wrongly because I got the appointment but I have to pay for it an amount that is more than the visa fee its self gbp124 as you see in the picture. Here in Uganda we use TSLcantact. So I don't know if the appointment is paid for or its covered in the visa fee.[image]

Comment: It looks like you purchased access to a "premium lounge" and a "flexi appointment," which are optional premium services. Did you intend to purchase those?

Comment: Your gmail address is visible in that image, you might want to black it out...

Comment: No I didn't intend to purchase those services. can they be changed??

Comment: It looks like you haven't actually paid yet. Can you cancel your appointment and make a new one without the extra services?